# SQL Server: how to select rows when changes happen?

Tags: sql-server

I have a question how to select row when changes happen.
Here is the table:

```
CreationDate | Value 
2019-06-04   | apple 
2019-06-01   | apple
2019-05-30   | apple 
2019-04-01   | orange 
2019-03-01   | apple
2019-02-01   | apple 
2019-01-01   | orange
```

If value doesn't change, then remove from the table.
I sort by date from new to old.
I want select value changes rows.

I expect a table like this:

```
CreationDate | Value
2019-05-30   | apple
2019-04-01   | orange
2019-02-01   | apple
2019-01-01   | orange
```

I want a table of which changes happened.

Comment: I'm looking at your sample table and the expected results and I don't detect a pattern that relates to your question _how remove row in which one value is same as last row_.  Could you provide some more information?  Also, please update your question to remove the images of the data and add actual `insert` statements.  That will help us address your question in a more timely manner.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHodgin. I remove the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you want.  You want to look into using the LEAD function.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
    CreationDate DATE NOT NULL
    , [Value] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @T
    (CreationDate, [Value])
VALUES ('6/4/2019', 'apple')
    , ('6/1/2019', 'apple')
    , ('5/30/2019', 'apple')
    , ('4/30/2019', 'orange')
    , ('4/1/2019', 'orange')
    , ('3/1/2019', 'apple')
    , ('2/1/2019', 'orange')

;WITH CTE_Source AS
    (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT CreationDate, [Value], LEAD([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PriorValue
    FROM @T AS T
    ORDER BY T.CreationDate, T.[Value]
    )
SELECT CreationDate, [Value] 
FROM CTE_Source
WHERE PriorValue IS NULL OR PriorValue <> [Value]
```

Comment: Thanks, That's exact I want. Thanks you. This response is so quick.

Comment: how can I do if there is a Farm column too and I want to capture changes that only happen for the same farm? imagine each record in the example @T is doubled, one with value "farmA", one with "farmB" for the Farm column.

Comment: I am also curious if this would work faster then https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565970/1134197

Comment: On mobile, not going to attempt a full code solution, but adding the “partition by farm” to the lead clause would do it (and of course adding it to the select list).  As for performance; this will probably do better than the example you linked.   They used a correlated sub query (or MySQL specific syntax, out of scope) and will do poorly.   Whereas with the proper indexes my solution will require a single pass and sort of the data.

Comment: what if the sorting in the subquery in linked example is moved to a CTE. will they perform the same then?

Comment: it works sir, and yours is much faster. I needed to replace LEAD with LAG though after adding partition by farm. thanks a lot.